# Pandas - Adding individual Z-Scores to each row based on an id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a Pandas data-frame with a game_id, player_id, and playtime column. I would like to add a z-score rating for each row to find how much from the norm, in terms of playtime, they are for each given game. How would I go through and add each one of these scores to a new column for the data-frame? Let me know if there's anything I need to clarify.

Comment: What does your data look like and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way and more efficient (fastest) is using the function `apply` of the data frame. First define the function of how you calculate the new column, and then apply it with the `apply` function:

```
def creating_new_column(row):
    #Adapt your code for the way you calculate the z score
    return ((row["playtime "])/2)

df["z_score"]=df.apply(lambda row: creating_new_column (row), axis=1)
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to be working, just trying to get the z-score formula to work now.